# Delete a record in MYSQL using playframework and Form<T>

Tags: mysql, playframework

Hi I am new to Play framework.I would like to implement CRUD operation using MYSQL database in play framework.

i have able to successfully delete, update the entire table, but not able to successfully delete the single record.  I want to pass the values from html.

```
index.scala.html

@(message: String)

@main("Welcome to Play") {

 <ul id="bars">

    </ul>

<form action="@routes.Application.addBar()" method="post">
    <label for="name"> Enter Your name</label>  <input name="name"/> <br>
    <label for="place"> Enter Your place</label>  <input name="place"/> <br>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>

<form action="@routes.Application.getBars()" method="get">
    <label for="retrieve"> Retrieve the details from table </label>
      <input type="submit"/>
</form>

<form action="@routes.Application.deleteBar()" method="get">
<label for="name"> Enter Your name to be deleted</label>  <input name="name"/> <br>
<input type="submit" value="Delete single record"/>
</form>

<form action="@routes.Application.updateBar()" method="post">
    <label for="name"> Enter Your name</label>  <input  name="name"/> <br>
    <label for="place"> Enter Your place</label>  <input name="place"/> <br>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
}
```

Application.java

```
package controllers;

import com.avaje.ebean.Ebean;
import com.avaje.ebean.SqlUpdate;
import java.util.List;
import models.Bar;
import play.*;
import play.data.Form;
import play.db.ebean.Model;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.twirl.api.Content;
import views.html.*;
import play.libs.Json;
public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result index() {
        int rowCount1 = Bar.find.findRowCount();

        return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
    }

    public static Result addBar() {
        Bar bar = Form.form(Bar.class).bindFromRequest().get();
        bar.save();
        return redirect(routes.Application.index());
    }

    public static Result Login() { 
        Bar bar = Form.form(Bar.class).bindFromRequest().get();
        bar.save();
        return redirect(routes.Application.index());
    }
    public static Result getBars(){
        List<Bar> bars = new Model.Finder(String.class, Bar.class).all();
        return ok(Json.toJson(bars));
    }

 public static Result deleteBar(String name) {

    SqlUpdate down = Ebean.createSqlUpdate("DELETE FROM bar WHERE name = :param1 ");
    down.setParameter("param1", bar.name);
    int deletedCount = down.execute();
    return ok("Deleted " + deletedCount + " record(s) " + bar.name);
}

}
```

route is as below:

```
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()
POST    /bars2                      controllers.Application.addBar()
GET     /bars                       controllers.Application.getBars()
GET     /bars1                      controllers.Application.deleteBars()
GET     /updateBar1/                controllers.Application.Login()

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

What i would like to do is:

1. I am using direct SQL query for DELETE,  but i want to know how i can achieve the same 
   Form class for mapping models - it will help for data validation also.  Please provide the pseudo code...   I went through the below stuff, but no luck

[Form class link](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaForms)

Comment: deleteBar method is using param but you didn't define in routes and deleteBar method name param is not using

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the Form for deleting records - what for? All you need is identifier or param to search for, you have two ways - first is that you showing with `SqlUpdate` second is with Ebean's method:

```
List<Bar> bars = Bar.find.where().eq("name", name).findList();
for (Bar bar : bars) {
    bar.delete();
}
```

If you want to delete single record by its `@Id` field you can just do it with (if you're sure that Bar with this ID exists):

```
Bar.find.ref(barId).delete();
```

Comment: when i use this it showing error in find as well as name part....                       List<Bar> bars = bar.find.where().eq("name", name).findList();
        for (Bar bar : bars) {
            bar.delete();
        }

Comment: solved it.                                                                                                         Bar bar = Form.form(Bar.class).bindFromRequest().get();
        List<Bar> bars = Ebean.find(Bar.class).where().eq("name",bar.name).findList();
        Ebean.delete(bars);  
        return ok(bar.name);